# How to access this.$apollo.query in the Vuex store with Nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxtjs

Keep getting that query is undefined... Could anyone tell me how access this.$apollo.query in the Vuex store with Nuxtjs?

```
import gqlGetAllTags from '~/apollo/queries/gqlGetAllTags.gql'

@Module({
  stateFactory: true,
  namespaced: true,
  name: 'products',
})
export default class Products extends VuexModule {
  product: Array<object> = []

  @Mutation
  GET_PRODUCT(product: Array<object>) {
    this.product = product
  }

  @Action({ rawError: true })
  async getProduct() {
    const collection = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: gqlGetAllTags,
      variables: {
        handle: 'nirvana',
      },
    })
    this.context.commit('GET_PRODUCT', collection)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Appolo provider in the Vuex action like this.

```
const collection = await this.app.apolloProvider.clients.defaultClient
  .query({
    query: gqlGetAllTags,
    variables: {
      handle: 'nirvana',
    },
  })
```